# What is the purpose of defining just one class in any header file and not including the entire header file containing such a class?

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of defining just one class in any header file and not including the entire header file containing such a class?

For example, I have found in some headers that there are some classes declarations in there like:

```
#include "blabla.h"
#include "mehmeh.h" 
class myClass; 

/*

Some code using myClass 

*/
```

What is the purpose of using this kind of declaration?

Comment: Hint: *"Thanks in ->advance<- for any comment"*

Comment: The main benefit is that it takes a shorter time to compile than including the header because the compiler knows it exists, but doesn't have to fill in all the details it doesn't need.

Comment: I've edited the text to consistently use "declaration" rather than mixing "declaration" and "definition". The two are related, but **not** interchangeable. `class MyClass;` is a declaration, not a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a forward declaration of a class. It lets you define pointers and references to the class that you define, without pulling in the entire definition.

The most important reason to do it is when you cannot do it in any other way, due to a circular reference:

```
class Parent;
class Child {
    Parent *parent;      // Child must reference Parent
    string name;
};
class Parent {
    Child *children[32]; // Parent must reference Children
};
```

Another reason is speeding up the compile: including a large header simply to declare a pointer may considerably slow down the compilation.

Answer (score 4):

It is called a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) It lets you tell the compiler that there is a type with that name but the header file doesn't need to know the details about that type.

This reduces the includes in your headers and reduces compile times.

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 14882, 1st, 3.9.6: "A class that has been declared but not defined, or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely defined object type. ... The size and layout of an instance of an incompletely defined object type is unknown."

K&R 2nd, p212: "Objects with an incomplete type ... may be mentioned in contexts where their [concrete] size is not needed."

Useful for opaque pointers, Cheshire Cat, pimpl, and so forth, or indeed any context where dereferencing is not required, not desired, or perhaps not even possible.